# Flow Screen shows two headings in Community page

Tags: community, visual-workflow, visual-flows

I have a visual flow which runs on a button click.  When the button is clicked a modal window appears showing a title - the label of the button - and a spinner:

[image]

When the flow returns a screen the spinner disappears and my screen message is displayed correctly; however for some reason a second title then appears:

[image]

The second title appears regardless of what header, footer or buttons I have enabled on the flow screen and both headings always exactly match the button label.

Anyone have any idea how I can stop this second label from appearing?  I've not been able to find any relevant information about this on any official sources!  The community is based on the Partner Central template, if that makes any difference.

Thanks

Comment: facing the same issue, anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug - [here's the Salesforce Documentation](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000019QKnQAM&title=screen-flows-launched-by-quick-actions-display-duplicate-labels-in-communities)

Comment: Excellent, thanks.  I'll subscribe to that bug and look forward to a fix!